# the think of bit shift in twitter snowflake IdWorker

Tags: twitter, bit, shift

who can explain code that it's the core of the twitter snowflake.

```
long nextId = ((timestamp - twepoch) << this.timestampLeftShift)
            | (this.workerId << this.workerIdShift) | (this.sequence);
```

i want to know that the think of the algorithm,why does it implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter's snowflake service creates unique ids in a distributed environment.  A number of worker processes can each assign unique ids.  The ids consist of three components: the time, a worker id, and a sequence number.  The line of code you show simple shifts those three components so that they don't overlap in the 64-bit result, and or's them together to create a single 64-bit result.

Comment: hi,Ned Batchelder,That means i can change its algorithm by myself such as the under of code:

    long nextId = ((timestamp - twepoch) << 2)
            | (this.workerId << 3) | (this.sequence<<5);

and is it that as your answer?

Comment: im test the above of the code by concurrency 10 thread:long nextId = ((timestamp - twepoch) << 2) | (this.workerId << 3) | (this.sequence<<5),the result of id can be repeat,whats about the code.

Comment: I didn't say you could change the code willy-nilly and it would continue to work.  The shift amounts depend on the size of the three components.  It's important that they not overlap.

Comment: i cant unstand that the left shift amounts about timestampLeftShift,workerIdShift and why the sequence do not left shift? thanks.

Comment: @snageyang: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.  Experiment with different values of shifting to see what they do.